# Calculate probability vector from sample data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spatial

I'd like to compare two distributions using Jensen-Shannon Divergence metric. To do this, I need two **probability vectors**. From the [scipy.spatial documentation](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html).

> scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon(p, q, base=None)[source]
>
> Parameters:
>
> p(N,) array_like left **probability vector**
>
> q(N,) array_like right **probability vector**

**Question**

How can I calculate probability vectors from sample data?

**Example:**

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.normal(size=100)
x2 = np.random.normal(size=100)

p = 

q = 

jsd_metric = distance.jensenshannon(p, q)
```

Can I accomplish this using `scipy.stats.norm.pdf()`?

```
p = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x1)
q = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability distribution (the probabilty vector in `scipy`) is the underying frequency distribution divided by the number of samples, so

```
p = np.histogram(x1)[0] / len(x1)    
q = np.histogram(x2)[0] / len(x2)
```

**Note:**

```
np.sum(p) == 1
np.sum(q) == 1
```